# iphone vectors, libraries handling and generating or Flash?

Tags: iphone, flash, vector-graphics

I'd like to port a Flash application to iPhone.

I like flash for a lot of reasons and would prefer to use it for content generation. However there are a [few downsides I am told](http://floatlearning.com/2010/03/optimizing-your-flash-content-for-iphone-deployment/), like at least 3.5 MB per app.

So while using Flash would make it easier to extend the current pipeline to include iPhone content, I was wondering what other choices are there for dealing with vector assets. I'm looking to bring in assets from Flash (or illustrator) easily, be able to add placeholders that can be replaced, and package them so that they can be updated easily from iOS.

Will most likely end up outsourcing the app creation, but I would like to know what the choices are before deciding what route to go.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know (and as i tried in my projects) you can use vector graphics just via pdf or files, then you can manage and load them in 2 way: using UIWebView and loading them (or link them in html files) or (and this could be your case) using Quartz 2D (see "Quartz 2D Programming Guide") and drawing them (.pdf files) in your objects...

Comment: These are the two things I came across (Quartz 2D and UIWebView). Any idea how I could replace assets with these? Let's say I have a placeholder among the graphics that I need to replace, or access by a name/id, is it possible?